# extract entities in symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony

In one of my controller action I can get all the entries by -

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('TestBuilderBundle:Questions')->findAll();
```

this line gives me all the an array object -

```
 array(1) {   [0]=>   object(stdClass)#318 (4) {
     ["__CLASS__"]=>
     string(37) "Test\BuilderBundle\Entity\Questions"
     ["id"]=>
     int(3)
     ["question"]=>
     string(24) "question;ans1;ans2;ans3;"
     ["type"]=>
     string(8) "checkbox"   } }
```

How can i extract this object to get -

```
["question"]=>
    string(24) "question;ans1;ans2;ans3;"
```

I need to manipulate "**question;ans1;ans2;ans3;**" for my application. Is there any way in symfony2?

Comment: You might want to create a custom function into your repository and build your query with the DBAL QueryBuilder

Comment: $entities[0] will give you the first entity.  It's just a fancy array.  Use foreach to process each entity.

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic beginning point of what already suggested from @AlexandruFurculita:

```
//Test/BuilderBundle/Entity/QuestionsRepository.php
class QuestionsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    ...
    public function getByColumns($columns)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select(implode(', ', array_map(function ($item) { return 'q.'.$item; }, $columns)))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}

// and inside your controller
$questions = $em->getRepository('TestBuilderBundle:Questions')->getByColumns(['question', 'whatheverElse']);
```